# Automatically killing mongod process on mac os shutdown

Tags: mongodb, macos-sierra

Since everytime I forget to manually kill the mongod process, the databases need to be repaired. I use a command `pidof` I believe I used brew to install this which returns the pid number of the process such as:

```
$pidof mongod 
44512
```

I am certain this can be | piped to some script and cleanly kill the daemon before shutdown preventing all sorts of problems with the mongodb. Can you help?

I am using MacOS Sierra.

Comment: Why not just use launchd?

Answer (score 0):

As MacOS probably uses the Linux build of MongoDB you could try to use the `--shutdown` option which is mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--shutdown). It should cleanly shutdown the DB.

> The --shutdown option cleanly and safely terminates the mongod process. When invoking mongod with this option you must set the --dbpath option either directly or by way of the configuration file and the --config option.
>
> The --shutdown option is available only on Linux systems.

Further more if you look into the [tutorials](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/) within the documentation you will see that you also could use the following commands on a mongo shell, which should be usable from within a script:

```
use admin
db.shutdownServer()
```

The third method listed within the documentation is indeed a simple kill. So it might depend on how MacOS handles `kill` in comparison to Linux. So explicitly sending `SIGTERM` rather than `SIGKILL` by using `kill -2` should gracefully stop it.